# Missing subnet referenced 'GatewaySubnet' in virtual network 'MyNetwork'

Tags: azure, subnet, azure-virtual-network

I've built a network in Azure that contains two subnets, Back and Front.

I'm now trying to create a gateway using Set-AzureVNetConfig but I'm getting a missing subnet called GatewaySubnet. This word does not exist anywhere in my scripts and Googling the word returns no results so it cannot be a reserved word.

```
<NetworkConfiguration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2011/07/NetworkConfiguration">
<VirtualNetworkConfiguration>
  <Dns />
  <LocalNetworkSites>
    <LocalNetworkSite name="lnt">
      <AddressSpace>
        <AddressPrefix>10.55.10.0/24</AddressPrefix>
      </AddressSpace>
      <VPNGatewayAddress>1.2.3.4</VPNGatewayAddress>
    </LocalNetworkSite>
  </LocalNetworkSites>
  <VirtualNetworkSites>
    <VirtualNetworkSite name="net" AffinityGroup="ag">
      <AddressSpace>
        <AddressPrefix>10.10.0.0/16</AddressPrefix>
      </AddressSpace>
      <Subnets>
        <Subnet name="Front">
          <AddressPrefix>10.10.1.0/24</AddressPrefix>
        </Subnet>
        <Subnet name="Back">
          <AddressPrefix>10.10.2.0/24</AddressPrefix>
        </Subnet>
      </Subnets>
      <Gateway>
        <ConnectionsToLocalNetwork>
          <LocalNetworkSiteRef name="lnt" />
        </ConnectionsToLocalNetwork>
      </Gateway>
    </VirtualNetworkSite>
  </VirtualNetworkSites>
</VirtualNetworkConfiguration>
```

Why does Azure think my config file is missing a subnet called GatewaySubnet?

Answer (score 1):

Taking a guess that this is a point-to-site network (and it looks like one). If that's the case, you need to add the gateway subnet (you can see this in the portal, for point-to-site network configuration). You can add this from the *Configure*  tab: scroll to the bottom and look at **virtual network address spaces** - you'll see a button to add the gateway subnet. If you do this, and then export your network, you'll see a `GatewaySubnet` element.

Comment: This is the GUI solution. I wanted to create the network with Powershell. However, adding a subnet called GatewaySubnet achieved my goal. It's clear GatewaySubnet is a reserved word, despite zero Google hits.

Comment: Try Bing :) Ok, only half-joking. 2nd hit for me: [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/igorpag/archive/2013/08/27/manually-adding-a-vpn-gateway-to-azure-virtual-network.aspx) post, describing `GatewaySubnet` as reserved word, its usage, etc.

Comment: Believing Google didn't index some of Microsoft's pages, even Bing translates it to "Gateway<space>Subnet". But yes, your link worked. Thanks!